# Passing MetaData to Custom Loss Function

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow2.0, loss-function

I'd like to create a custom loss function that depends on metadata.  In the simplest form I'd like to multiply the loss by a per batch weight (determined by the meta data).

For simplicity, consider passing the desired weight directly.  Here are two attempts at loss functions:

```py
def three_arg_loss(loss_func):
    """ a loss function that takes 3 args"""
    def _loss(target,output,weight):
        return weight*loss_func(target,output)
    return _loss

def target_list_loss(loss_func):
    """ a loss function that expects the target arg to be [target,weight]"""
    def _loss(target,output):
        weight=target[1]
        target=target[0]
        return weight*loss_func(target,output)
    return _loss
```

When I tried to train I got the following:

- `three_arg_loss`: `TypeError: tf___loss() missing 1 required positional argument: 'weight'`

But of course, I tripled checked and I was indeed passing 3 args

- `target_list_loss`: `ValueError: Shapes (None, None, None) and (None, None, None, 4) are incompatible`

And again after triple checking, I was indeed passing `[target,weight]` as the target argument. I was worried here I might have messed up the order of the arguments to the loss function so i flipped them just to be sure and got `ValueError: Shapes (None, None, 4) and (None, None, None, None) are incompatible`

Thoughts? Whats the correct/best approach to have a loss function that is dependent on additional data (in my case geographic location)?

As requested below here is a complete (but silly) example showing the errors

```py
BATCH_SIZE=2
SIZE=3
STEPS=8
EPOCHS=3
NB_CLASSES=4


def gen_inpt(ch_in):
    return tf.random.uniform((BATCH_SIZE,SIZE,SIZE,ch_in))

def gen_targ(nb_classes):
    t=tf.random.uniform((BATCH_SIZE,SIZE,SIZE),maxval=nb_classes,dtype=tf.int32)
    return tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(t,num_classes=nb_classes)

def gen(ch_in,ch_out):
    return ( ( gen_inpt(ch_in), gen_targ(ch_out) ) for b in range(BATCH_SIZE*STEPS*EPOCHS) )

def gen_targ_list(ch_in,ch_out):
    return ( ( gen_inpt(ch_in), [gen_targ(ch_out), tf.fill(1,2222)] ) for b in range(BATCH_SIZE*STEPS*EPOCHS) )

def gen_3args(ch_in,ch_out):
    return ( ( gen_inpt(ch_in), gen_targ(ch_out), tf.fill(1,10000.0) ) for b in range(BATCH_SIZE*STEPS*EPOCHS) )


class Toy(tf.keras.Model):
    
    def __init__(self,nb_classes):
        super(Toy, self).__init__()
        self.l1=layers.Conv2D(32,3,padding='same')
        self.l2=layers.Conv2D(nb_classes,3,padding='same')
        
    def call(self,x):
        x=self.l1(x)
        x=self.l2(x)
        return x

def test_loss(loss_func):
    def _loss(target,output):
        return loss_func(target,output)
    return _loss


def target_list_loss(loss_func):
    def _loss(target,output):
        weight=target[1]
        target=target[0]
        return weight*loss_func(target,output)
    return _loss


def three_arg_loss(loss_func):
    def _loss(target,output,weight):
        return weight*loss_func(target,output)
    return _loss


loss_func=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()

loss_test=test_loss(loss_func)
loss_targ_list=target_list_loss(loss_func)
loss_3arg=three_arg_loss(loss_func)

def test_train(loss,gen):
    try: 
        model=Toy(NB_CLASSES)    
        model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss=loss,
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
        model.fit(gen(6,NB_CLASSES),steps_per_epoch=STEPS,epochs=EPOCHS)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

#
# RUN TESTS
#
test_train(loss_test,gen)
test_train(loss_targ_list,gen_targ_list)
test_train(loss_3arg,gen_3args)
```

Example extending Loss (gives same results)

```py
class TargListLoss(tf.keras.losses.Loss):
    
    def __init__(self,loss_func):
        super(TargListLoss,self).__init__()
        self.loss_func=loss_func
        
    def call(self,target,output):
        weight=target[1]
        target=target[0]
        return weight*self.loss_func(target,output)
```

Comment: Post the code that produces the error.

Comment: @gobrewers14 done!

Comment: Is there a reason you are writing these loss functions as closures? This seems unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @gobrewers14 honestly I did it for making this SO question simpler :)  Normally I'd extend [Loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/Loss).  My guess is the particular errors I'm getting are uninteresting because there is a better way to do what I am trying to do.  Note the `test_loss` example is only there to make sure in the trivial case my code runs.

Comment: Yeah subclassing [Loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/Loss) with a weight argument in call() seems like a lot simpler.

Comment: @gobrewers14 - its cleaner (but more code). That said ```TargListLoss(tf.keras.losses.Loss)``` (see edited post) will give the same errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SampleWeights!**

I was trying to build custom loss functions that weighted the loss on a per sample basis but this is exactly what `sample_weights` are for.

Apologies all for the silly question - though hopefully this keeps others from repeating my mistake. I think missed this because originally I was planning on determining the weight by passing metadata directly to the loss function. In retrospect it doesn't make sense to include the meta-to-weight logic in your loss-function as it is application dependent.

For completeness the code below shows how passing a third arg from the generator does indeed weight each sample:

```py
BATCH_SIZE=2
SIZE=3
STEPS=8
EPOCHS=3
NB_CLASSES=4


def gen_inpt(ch_in):
    return tf.random.uniform((BATCH_SIZE,SIZE,SIZE,ch_in))

def gen_targ(nb_classes):
    t=tf.random.uniform((BATCH_SIZE,SIZE,SIZE),maxval=nb_classes,dtype=tf.int32)
    return tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(t,num_classes=nb_classes)
        
def gen_3args(ch_in,ch_out,dummy_sw):
    if dummy_sw:
        return ( ( gen_inpt(ch_in), gen_targ(ch_out), tf.convert_to_tensor(dummy_sw) ) for b in range(BATCH_SIZE*STEPS*EPOCHS) )
    else:
        return ( ( gen_inpt(ch_in), gen_targ(ch_out) ) for b in range(BATCH_SIZE*STEPS*EPOCHS) )

    
class Toy(tf.keras.Model):
    
    def __init__(self,nb_classes):
        super(Toy, self).__init__()
        self.l1=layers.Conv2D(32,3,padding='same')
        self.l2=layers.Conv2D(nb_classes,3,padding='same')
        
    def call(self,x):
        x=self.l1(x)
        x=self.l2(x)
        return x
    
loss_func=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()

def test_train(loss,gen):
    try: 
        model=Toy(NB_CLASSES)    
        model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
        model.fit(gen,steps_per_epoch=STEPS,epochs=EPOCHS)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

# #
# # RUN TESTS
# #
print('None: unweighted')
test_train(loss_func,gen_3args(6,NB_CLASSES,None))
print('ones: same as None')
test_train(loss_func,gen_3args(6,NB_CLASSES,[1,1]))
print('100s: should be roughly 100 times the loss of None')
test_train(loss_func,gen_3args(6,NB_CLASSES,[100,100]))
print('[0,10]: should be roughly 1/2 the 100s loss ')
test_train(loss_func,gen_3args(6,NB_CLASSES,[0,100]))
```